# MySQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

This is an update query between two SugarCRM tables, both INNODB
Seems simple enough but when run it doesn't update the records

Query executed OK, 0 rows affected

We have run a select query to make sure that we have match on the ids
Have also tried update ... select variant

Have checked the indexes for both tables -- present and apparently OK 
Does anyone have any tips.

```
UPDATE accounts new LEFT join  accounts_old old
ON (new.id = old.id) 
SET new.billing_address_country = old.billing_address_country
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Unless accompanied by WHERE... IS NULL, OUTER JOINs in UPDATE queries are vanishingly rare. Are you sure that's what you want?

Apart from that there's nothing wrong with this query...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;

CREATE TABLE accounts(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,billing_address_county VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts_old;

CREATE TABLE accounts_old(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,billing_address_county VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (1,'Hale County');
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (2,'Perry County');

INSERT INTO accounts_old VALUES (1,'Hale County');
INSERT INTO accounts_old VALUES (2,'Tuscaloosa County');


UPDATE accounts new 
  JOIN accounts_old old 
    ON old.id = new.id 
   SET new.billing_address_county = old.billing_address_county;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
   Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

   mysql> SELECT * FROM accounts;
   +----+------------------------+
   | id | billing_address_county |
   +----+------------------------+
   |  1 | Hale County            |
   |  2 | Tuscaloosa County      |
   +----+------------------------+
   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Strawberry -- thanks very much for the detailed response. A clarification -- does this mean that the original left join equates to an outer join in MySQL

Comment: Sort of. There are two kinds of OUTER JOIN; LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN. In MySQL the OUTER keyword (like the INNER keyword of an INNER JOIN) is optional, and frequently omitted. In fact, there's really only one kind of OUTER JOIN - because theoretically, every LEFT JOIN can be rewritten as a RIGHT JOIN (and vice versa), although in complicated queries I find it difficult to figure out how to do that.

Comment: OK will do a bit of study on those implicits. Thanks again for your response -- invaluable

Comment: Interesting aftercomment -- took all this back to the database and carried out these steps

Comment: Interesting aftercomment -- took all this back to the database and carried out these steps:
 - Tried update as suggested - NG
 - SELECTed the join fields = fine 239 rows
 - Updated the target field from another field in the same table -Fine 
 - Copied old and new tables SQL to new database 
 - Tried suggested query - NG 
 - Tried suggested query from another field in the old table Worked !!
 - Tried coping the old source data to a new field in the same table
   then tried coping from that field into the new table
 - Still NG

Comment: Conclusion: Data corruption in old table ??
Looks like some typing practice coming up - Sigh! 
PS both fields/tables are default UTF8